# Alternative collecting checkbox value using push pull of lodash

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I want to ditch lodash and use es6 as much as possible, other area is doing well, especially I'm using array helper method like map and spread really help, but I can't refactor below code

```
onChangeCheckbox(e) {
    const { input } = this.props;

    const arr = input[ e.target.name ] || [];

    const checked = e.target.checked;
    if (checked) {
        arr.push(e.target.value);
    }
    else {
        pull(arr, e.target.value);
    }

    this.props.onChange( e.target.name, arr );
}
```

It's ok for me but other members complain it's hard to read, any clue how to make it become better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter the array, and assign the results back to arr:

```
arr = arr.filter((value) => value !== e.target.value)
```

In react it's better to replace, and not mutate because the change detection makes shallow comparisons, so I would replace the `Array#push` as well.

```
onChangeCheckbox(e) {
    const { input } = this.props;

    let arr = input[ e.target.name ] || [];

    const checked = e.target.checked;

    if (checked) {
        arr = [...arr, e.target.value];
    }
    else {
        arr = arr.filter((value) => value !== e.target.value)
    }

    this.props.onChange( e.target.name, arr );
}
```

Comment: Why do you think `[...arr, e.target.value]` is better than `arr.push(e.target.value)`?

Comment: Because `push` mutates the array, and react shallow comparison won't catch that change.

Comment: @OriDrori i think `arr.push()` and `arr = [...arr, 'a']` both will mutate the `arr` one by assigning new value and one by pushing the value correct?

Comment: I don't think it's a problem. `this.props.onChange` will be called with necessary array data, so mutating or not is not relevant. Original code uses mutation and I assume it works.

Comment: @MayankShukla - `arr = [...arr, 'a']` creates a new array

Comment: @dfsq - `onChange` will be called, however, if another component uses the result, it won't rerender, since he won't detect the change.

Comment: @OriDrori ohh got it, was a confusion with the array reference part thanks :)

Comment: It will of course. But we don't know how this result is used. Well anyway, I don't think spread is justified here.

Comment: You're right that in the context of this function. However, in the context of react, this array is probably part of the state, and in addition to shallow checks, this is what react has to say about [mutating the state](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#state) (last 2 paragraphs).

Comment: I know what react says about mutation, but I'm saying if you have `<ComponentOne inputs={this.state.inputs} />` and <ComponentTwo inputs={this.state.inputs} />` both using same state slice `input`, then mitating inputs in the first will still be reflected in the second. But anyway, I agree that pure functions are better in many cases.

Comment: Indeed. In your example, you would actually have to replace the whole `state.input` object, and it won't matter if you pushed the value or used spread.